# Laravel Too few arguments to function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I have a simple app for generating some code using Laravel, now I am trying to pass unique id to to my controller with the url.

This is this method that should receive the ID:

```
 public function code($code_id)
 {
     $settings = Setting::find($code_id);

     return view('pages.settings.code', compact('settings'));
 }
```

And this is my view-file where I pass the ID:

```
<a href="{{ route('settings.code', $settings->code_id) }}">
    {{ __('Generate Code') }}
</a>
```

When I check the URL I get:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8001/settings/code?K1zMXRZG4
```

Here is my route:

```
Route::get('settings/code', [
    'as' => 'settings.code', 
    'uses' => 'SettingController@code'
]);

Route::resource('settings', "SettingController");
```

But I get the following error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR)
Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\SettingController::code(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Show us your `settings.code` route

Comment: ok, what I would suggest what KFoobar tell you in the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define any parameters that should be passed to the method in your route:

```
Route::get('/settings/code/{code_id}', 'MyController@code')
    ->name('settings.code');
```

That will pass `$code_id` to the `code()`-method in your controller.

If you don´t define the parameter in your route, it will be passed as a parameter in `Request`-object instead - like all querystrings - and you need to fetch it like this in your controller:

```
$code_id = $request->query('code_id');
```